# Differences in build on Jenkins?

Tags: linux, git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I configure Jenkins to build a project from git, i'm using maven:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

However, the project build is incomplete:

[image]

In a terminal the build occurred correct:

[image]

In both case no error occurs and a build is finished with sucess.

I don't know exactly, why the differences are happening.

Comment: Compare the build output from Jenkins and your terminal.

Comment: The output is practically the same, except because I use in terminal mvn clean install and jenkins use mvn install

Comment: It is as if It wasn't doing a pull from GIT repository, when I update a file, there are  no changes in Jenkins source in workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making two mistakes:

1 - At the first time I was not especifying the correct branch

2 - For some reason, that I don't know exactly, the first workspce that I had created, the pull was not working, then I deleted my workspace and recreated it.

Then it's worked fine for me.

Thanks for all.